# WCF Service 4.0 --- maxReceivedMessageSize ain't effectively used

Tags: wcf, web-config, maxreceivedmessagesize

I am building a WCF service with framework 4.0 for a special application in house. I have a big array of object to pass from the server to the WPF client. If the array is small enough, everything works fine but if it's over the standart size limit, it doesn't. I tried to change the web.config with the parameter maxReceivedMessageSize but the max size limit error still show with the original value of 65536 even if I put a extreme maxReceivedMessageSize of 1000000000. Here is the web.config as now :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="commonBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="longConnections" maxBufferSize ="1000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name ="MiralisWebServices.HMI_Router" behaviorConfiguration="commonBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="longConnections" 
              contract="MiralisWebServices.IHMI_Router"/>
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I am still a beginner with web.config with framework 4.0. I hope you guys could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that setting change is also required on the client config.